# iOS : How to display search results in another table view ? And how to show suggestions while searching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, search, uisearchbar

Currently, what I am showing search result same tableview.

Now, I want to show results in another table view.

Here is one example of search & suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please drag another tableview in view and when you are going to search then display that data in upper table and hide and show the upper table on the basis of search. Also create an outlet of upper tableview and apply condition in TableViewDelegate and DataSource.

Comment: let me check it. I want one more thing is that, I want to show suggestions while typing in search bar. Do you have any idea, how to add it ?

Comment: when are you going to start typing then hit the api after 3 character and list out the suggestion and show in tableview.

Comment: If you have facing any issue please let me know.

Comment: Nikita Patil I think you get your answer.